# Add underline to customized package

Tags: ckeditor, underline

I am using CKEditor (v. 4.4.7) and am trying to include the underline feature. The full package has more buttons than my users need and the standard package doesn't include this button. I used the builder to customize. I started with the standard page and added (or maybe it was already there) "Basic Styles", which in the description says:

```
"This plugin adds the following basic formatting commands to the editor:

Bold
Italic
Underline
Strikethrough
Subscript
Superscript
"
```

When I run the editor in my code, I'm getting only Bold, Italic and Strikethrough. No underline (or subscript or superscript, for that matter). What do I need to do in order to get the other function(s)?

My config file:

```
    /**
  * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2015, CKSource - Frederico Knabben.       All rights reserved.
* For licensing, see LICENSE.md or http://ckeditor.com/license
*/

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
// Define changes to default configuration here.
// For complete reference see:
// http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

// The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for two toolbar rows.
config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
    { name: 'links' },
    { name: 'insert' },
    { name: 'forms' },
    { name: 'tools' },
    { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
    { name: 'others' },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
    { name: 'styles' },
    { name: 'colors' },
    { name: 'about' }
];

// Remove some buttons provided by the standard plugins, which are
// not needed in the Standard(s) toolbar.
config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';

// Set the most common block elements.
config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';

// Simplify the dialog windows.
config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: Reading is fundamental. Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to read the config that you pasted? It says:

```
// Remove some buttons provided by the standard plugins, which are
// not needed in the Standard(s) toolbar.
config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';
```

I hope that it's enough for the answer ;).